# how do I make this search both first names and last names?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this search function:

```
  def self.search(query)
    where('customer_phone_number LIKE ? OR lower(first_name) LIKE ? OR lower(last_name) LIKE ?', "%#{query.downcase}%", "%#{query.downcase}%", "%#{query.downcase}%")
  end
```

which is great but if someone types a first AND last name into the search bar, nothing gets returned. how do I make it check the full name if the user enters both a first and last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sql function concat()

```
def self.search(query)
    where("customer_phone_number LIKE ? OR lower(first_name) LIKE ? OR lower(last_name) LIKE ? OR concat(lower(first_name),' ', lower(last_name)) like ?", "%#{query.downcase}%", "%#{query.downcase}%", "%#{query.downcase}%", "%#{query.downcase}%")
end
```